# Adding the sum of all the random numbers in a random number generator

Tags: c#

Hi, I am trying to add the sum of the random numbers in my random number gen to get the average of the random numbers that were generated also to display them in a message box. I can not do arrays. Here is what I have so far:

```
 class Program
    {
        static double average = 0;
        static double sum = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Random number = new Random();
            int min = int.MaxValue, max = int.MinValue;
            string result = "\tn    \n";

            for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)

            {
               int n = number.Next(0, 1000);
                // Console.WriteLine(n);

                if (n < min)
                    min = n;
                if (n > max)
                    max = n;

            }

            sum = sum + (number.Next()) ;
            average = sum / 100;


            int range = min - (min + 1);
            result += " \t"
                       + min
                       + " \t"
                       + max
                       + " \t"
                       + average
                       + " \t"
                       + sum
                       + " \t"
                       + range;

            MessageBox.Show(result, "Min = {0}, Max = {1}, Range = {2}");
        }
```

I would like a hint to solve this problem not a list of code that is just given to me. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: there needs to be a `sum = sum + ?` *inside* the loop.

Comment: in the loop is this correct    sum = sum +(n); which n represents my random number gen

Comment: The parenthesis are not needed, but that would work inside the loop. Remember to get rid of adding to sum outside the loop. Also, move the average and sum variable declarations into the function (where min already is).

Comment: thank you. I have been working on this a little while. I have not had many classes and time to figure this stuff out.. it is a 5 week class and its already been 3.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put this inside of the `for` loop:

```
sum = sum + n;
```

(or `sum += n;`)

Then after the loop, the average will be the sum divided by 100.

Also you can take out the `min` and `max` part, unless that is needed for something else.